# How to get wget on my non rooted Android device

Tags: linux, terminal

I installed an app from the Play Store called Material Terminal.
It allows me to enter Linux commands and run them such as: cd, mkdir, touch, etc.

I wonder if it is possible to get the wget command running on my non rooted device running Android 4.4.

If it is, than how?

Comment: Material Terminal is only an interface to the commands already present inside your phone. In order to get access to other commands, it would be best for you to use Termux, which is a self-contained barebones OS, not requiring any root privileges.

Comment: I checked Termux, it looks great, but requires Android 5.0 at minimum. I have a phone running 4.4. :-(

Comment: It would be best to include this info in your question.

Comment: I think it's possible to install `busybox` on non-rooted `Android` devices.

Comment: @ Arkadiusz Drabczyk   But how?

Comment: This free [Busybox](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=ru.meefik.busybox) (also [on Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.busybox)) claims it can work without root. Instructions in the app description. Not sure if it contains wget.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26775079/wget-in-android-terminal